Text file with over 700k row keep crashing when running the tool
I'm working with a text file that contains over 700,000 rows of data. I'm using the following VBA macro to copy the data from the text file and paste it into an Excel spreadsheet. However, after running for a few minutes, Excel keeps crashing. I'm looking for advice on how to handle such a large dataset more efficiently or how to prevent Excel from crashing during the process. Here’s the code I’m using:
Option Explicit
Sub ImportLargeTextFiles()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataArray() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim startTime As Double
    Dim lineCount As Long
    Dim chunkSize As Long
    Dim currentChunk() As String
    Dim filePath As String

    ' Disable screen updating and automatic calculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Start timer
    startTime = Timer

    ' Create FileSystemObject
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Select folder containing text files
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select Folder Containing Text Files"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            Set folder = fso.GetFolder(.SelectedItems(1))
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    ' Create or select the output worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Imported Data")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        ws.Name = "Imported Data"
    End If
    ws.Cells.Clear

    ' Set headers
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "File Name"
    ws.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Line Content"

    ' Initialize variables
    i = 2  ' Start from row 2 (after headers)
    chunkSize = 10000  ' Adjust this based on your needs and available memory

    ' Loop through each file in the folder
    For Each file In folder.Files
        If LCase(Right(file.Name, 4)) = ".txt" Then
            filePath = file.Path

            ' Open the file
            Open filePath For Input As #1

            ' Process the file in chunks
            Do While Not EOF(1)
                ReDim currentChunk(1 To chunkSize)
                lineCount = 0

                ' Read a chunk of lines
                Do While lineCount < chunkSize And Not EOF(1)
                    lineCount = lineCount + 1
                    Line Input #1, currentChunk(lineCount)
                Loop

                ' Resize the chunk array to actual size
                ReDim Preserve currentChunk(1 To lineCount)

                ' Prepare data array for the chunk
                ReDim dataArray(1 To lineCount, 1 To 2)
                For j = 1 To lineCount
                    dataArray(j, 1) = file.Name
                    dataArray(j, 2) = currentChunk(j)
                Next j

                ' Write the chunk to the worksheet
                ws.Cells(i, 1).Resize(lineCount, 2).Value = dataArray
                i = i + lineCount
            Loop

            ' Close the file
            Close #1
        End If
    Next file

    ' Format the worksheet
    With ws
        .Columns("A:B").AutoFit
        .Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
    End With

    ' Re-enable screen updating and automatic calculation
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    ' Display completion message
    MsgBox "Import completed in " & Format(Timer - startTime, "0.00") & " seconds", vbInformation
End Sub


What do the lines in the text file look like? Are they very long?

Yes, almost each row has 800 columns

How large is the source file?

File size is 1 GB.

Possible that's just "too big"...   Do you need to load all lines and all fields?

Microsoft Excel is a spreadsheet calculation application. It is not and never will be a storage for database dumps. Never understood why spreadsheet calculation sheets need one million rows at all.

Just curious. How much memory on your machine, and which OS you have. It occurred to me that expanding virtual memory might help. This post suggests this and also disabling add ins. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/excel-memory-amp-performance-limitation/m-p/4086864

Wouldn't PowerQuery be an alternative?

What version of Excel are you using? is it 32 or 64 bit?

@N R, Just sharing these memory management tips, which might help: https://fastercapital.com/content/VBA-Clear-Memory--Boosting-Excel-s-Speed--Clearing-Memory-via-VBA.html

So I haven't tried with a 1 GB file, but we did move a ~600 MB text file to an xlsb file, requiring we open excel and save the workbook to ensure appropriate extension/type, then imported the data.  As Tim wrote, it may just be that Excel is an inappropriate tool for the dataset; if it can be broken up, that may be more manageable with Excel, or another tool may be the better option.
